# Julia: Flux.jl: "function gradient does not accept keyword arguments"

Tags: julia, gradient, flux-machine-learning

I'm trying to use `Flux.jl v"0.6.10` (which I freshly installed and which looks like an awesome package) with `Julia Version 1.1.0` and copied the following code from the ["basic" section of the documation of flux.jl](https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/models/basics/)

```
using Flux.Tracker
f(x) = 3x^2 + 2x + 1;
df(x) = Tracker.gradient(f, x; nest = true)[1];
df(2)
```

However I got this error message:

```
ERROR: function gradient does not accept keyword arguments
Stacktrace:
 [1] kwfunc(::Any) at ./boot.jl:330
 [2] df(::Int64) at ./REPL[3]:1
 [3] top-level scope at none:0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well I just found that the version that I installed and update is the `v"0.6.10` (although I just ran `(v1.1) pkg> update Flux`). However in the documentation, the code above is `df(x) = Tracker.gradient(f, x)[1]` for the definition of the gradient (and not `df(x) = Tracker.gradient(f, x; nest = true)[1];`, which is valid for the version `v"0.8.3`)